# Make a button to add/subtract a value to a label which will show a corresponding picture to that number on the label

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiimage, uilabel

I'm self-learning and don't know what is wrong with my code and how to do a more shorter clean code?

I want the numbers only set between 1,2,3,4.
So I don't want negatives or any numbers greater than 4.
Numbers are showing up great and correctly on the simulator but the pictures get messed up.
It goes 1,2,3,4 and then messes up when going back 4,3,2,1.

```
- (IBAction)plusLevelPressed:(id)sender {
    int intValueFromFirstLabel = [_lvlLabel.text intValue];

    if(intValueFromFirstLabel != 4)
    {
        _lvlLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[_lvlLabel.text intValue]+1];
    }
    //change image according to lvl selection
    if(intValueFromFirstLabel == 0)
    {
        UIImage *lvl1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"lvl1.jpg"];
        [_lvlMap setImage:lvl1];
    }

    if(intValueFromFirstLabel == 1)
    {
        UIImage *lvl2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"lvl2.jpg"];
        [_lvlMap setImage:lvl2];
    }

    if(intValueFromFirstLabel == 2)
    {
        UIImage *lvl3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"lvl3.jpg"];
        [_lvlMap setImage:lvl3];
    }

    if(intValueFromFirstLabel == 3)
    {
        UIImage *lvl4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"lvl4.jpg"];
        [_lvlMap setImage:lvl4];
    } }

- (IBAction)minusLevelPressed:(id)sender {
    int intValueFromFirstLabel = [_lvlLabel.text intValue];

    if(intValueFromFirstLabel != 1)
    {
        _lvlLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[_lvlLabel.text intValue]-1];
    }

    //change image according to lvl selection
    if(intValueFromFirstLabel == 0)
    {
        UIImage *lvl1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"lvl1.jpg"];
        [_lvlMap setImage:lvl1];
    }

    if(intValueFromFirstLabel == 1)
    {
        UIImage *lvl2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"lvl2.jpg"];
        [_lvlMap setImage:lvl2];
    }

    if(intValueFromFirstLabel == 2)
    {
        UIImage *lvl3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"lvl3.jpg"];
        [_lvlMap setImage:lvl3];
    }

    if(intValueFromFirstLabel == 3)
    {
        UIImage *lvl4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"lvl4.jpg"];
        [_lvlMap setImage:lvl4];
    }

}
```

I'm learning this to build myself a better career, so I really appreciate all the help!
Thanks!

Comment: What does "messed up" mean? :D We can't read minds. What do you expect it to happen and what is really happening?

Answer (score 0):

Are you by chance, going:

```
[self plusLevel]; intValueFromFirstLabel == 0, _lvlLabel == 1 
[self plusLevel]; intValueFromFirstLabel == 1, _lvlLabel == 2
[self plusLevel]; intValueFromFirstLabel == 2, _lvlLabel == 3
[self plusLevel]; intValueFromFirstLabel == 3, _lvlLabel == 4
```

Then

```
[self minusLevel]; intValueFromFirstLabel == 4, _lvlLabel == 3 * 
[self minusLevel];
[self minusLevel];
[self minusLevel];
```

When you start going through minusLevel, intValueFromFirstLabel on first run is 4 because it takes the value of _lvlLabel HOWEVER, your minusLevel doesn't have a condition for

```
if(intValueFromFirstLabel == 4)
{

}
```

So what you're seeing I think is when you minus level, it appears to be 1 level behind, is that right?

Either way, I think you can refine your code to be shorter like this:

```
-(IBAction)plusLevelPressed:(id)sender
{
    int intValueFromFirstLabel = [_lvlLabel.text intValue];

    // only update level image if level is within 0 to 3
    if(intValueFromFirstLabel > -1 && intValueFromFirstLabel < 4)
    {
        [self setLevelImageForLevelNumber:intValueFromFirstLabel];

        _lvlLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[_lvlLabel.text intValue]+1];
    }
}

-(IBAction)minusLevelPressed:(id)sender
{
    int intValueFromFirstLabel = [_lvlLabel.text intValue];

    // only update level image if level is within 0 to 3
    if(intValueFromFirstLabel > -1 && intValueFromFirstLabel < 4)
    {
        [self setLevelImageForLevelNumber:intValueFromFirstLabel];

        _lvlLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[_lvlLabel.text intValue]-1];
    }
}

-(void)setLevelImageForLevelNumber:(int)levelNumber
{
    NSString *strImageName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"lvl%d.jpg", levelNumber + 1];
    UIImage *lvlImage = [UIImage imageNamed:strImageName];
    [_lvlMap setImage:lvlImage];
}
```

Comment: hi, thank you very much for your input, i like the new shorter code very much.

Comment: Unfortunately using your code the minusLevelPressed does not work at all because of "intValueFromFirstLabel < 4" but if i change the number to 5, it still ends up in a similar problem to mine. [sorry for my lack of explanation before, the problem in my original code is that when its at lvl4, and then minusLevelPressed it goes like this; "lvlLabel = 3 lvlmap = 4",then "2/4",then "1/3" then press again = "1/2"]     ps. sorry for late reply, i have been very tiring with work .